# facebook api appending #_=_ to my return uri

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the facebook php library to authenticate users to my app, it's working fine but for some reason facebook is appending the characters `#_=_` to the end of my return uri. I read that they did this if the `redirect_uri` parameter wasn't set but I do have it set, in fact I'm redirected to that URL successfully after I log in on facebook.

Here's how I get the login url:

```
$fbLoginUrl = $fb->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'email,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_photos,friends_photos',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://myapp.net/auth'
));
```

Everything works fine it's just a cosmetic thing I guess. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and a bug is filed here,
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20504

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Facebook developer blog, it was told that, if you explicitly set the `redirect_uri` param, you won't get the `#_=_` appended to the callback uri. But this is not the case. You still get those characters even on setting `redirect_url` field. But that won't have any effect on your flow.

Check this: [Session Redirect Behavior - setting redirect_uri explicitely](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20504)

Comment: sigh so I guess it's a facebook fail then :(

Answer (score 2):

You can *only* get rid of this client-side.

You might think that you could solve this server-side by redirecting to a URL without the anchor:

- facebook redirects to `http://MyFacebookRedirectUrl...#_=_`
- Then we redirect to some new URL, without the anchor

....But the `#_=_` reappears by magic in the browser address bar - how?

See James Pearce's answer at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/318390728250352 :

*"Some browsers will append the hash fragment from a URL to the end of a new URL to which they have been redirected (if that new URL does not itself have a hash fragment)."*

and also this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/17/url-fragments-and-redirects-anchor-hash-missing.aspx

> Firefox, Chrome, and Opera [and now IE10] will re-attach a URL
>   Fragment after a HTTP/3xx redirection has taken place, even though
>   that fragment was not present in the URL specified by the Location
>   header on the redirection response

So if you're just doing server side redirects from your Facebook redirect page, you're going to have to remove this client-side.

The other alternative is to redirect server-side to a URL that contains a different named anchor - but that doesn't really solve the problem and not all browsers will do the same thing.